# Make EditText behave as a TextView in code

Tags: android

How to make an EditText look like a TextView that is done in Java but not in XML..

I have seen how to do it using xml file like

```
style="@android:style/Widget.TextView"
android:editable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

but i want this to be done in java because i am not using any xml file for the layout..
everything is done in code itself ..
I am trying to use GestureListener in my code .. it worked fine for TextView but not EditText
So, anything to do for the EditText so that the GestureEvents can be implemented ?

Thanks,

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditText` is a subclass of `TextView` - so except for editing, what applies to `TextView` applies to `EditText` as well.

Comment: yes .. but i am trying to use gesture listeners on EditText.. it works fine for TextView but not for EditText

Answer (score 10):

```
EditText Et; // initialize your edittext//

Et.setCursorVisible(false);
Et.setLongClickable(false);
Et.setClickable(false);
Et.setFocusable(false);
Et.setSelected(false);
Et.setKeyListener(null);
Et.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

And you'll never see it like an EditText again.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved my day. I did:
        `editText.setFocusable(enable);`
        `editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(enable);`
        `editText.setLongClickable(enable);`

Answer (score 4):

add below two line into your edittext xml:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:inputType="none"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect way to  make EditText as TextView.

Use in your EditText.

```
<EditText
          android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="none"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:clickable="false"
          android:longClickable="false"
          android:inputType="none"/>
```

Comment: OP clearly asked to do this programmatically as OP already knew how to do it in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Make EditText behave as a TextView in code

try this

```
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:clickable="false"    
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:editable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I know this was a very old question, but I have to do this one of my apps and came up with a simple approach deduced from all the answers from Google/stack overflow. Suppose u want to make a edit text look like a text view and on button click make it editable, the procedure is as follows:

In your layout, set:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_postContent"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="This is a dummy text "
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_empimage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        style="?android:attr/textViewStyle" />
```

And in your `.java` set the color of the text by:

```
yourEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

before entering the `onClick` of button. And in the `onClick` of button:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)               getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(postContent, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);//shows   keyboard
int position = postContent.length();
Editable text = postContent.getText();
yourEditText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));//shows a border around your text view making it look like a edit text
yourEditTex.setEnabled(true);//enables the edit text which we disabled in layout file
yourEditTex.setCursorVisible(true);
Selection.setSelection(text,position-1);`//places the cursor at the end of the text
```

Now to make the edit text show again as a `textView`, on the `onClick` of another button:

```
String s = postContent.getText().toString();
yourEditText.setText(s);
yourEditText.setEnabled(false);
yourEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
yourEditText.setBackground(null);`
```

My answer covers two or three questions combined, but I hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add an border to EditText :
First Of all add an border.xml in Resources/Drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

**Second step :
   add   android:background="@drawable/border" to TextView**

```
 <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:id="@+id/dateFromTextView"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This was all I needed to create the effect.

In code:

```
ET.setFocusable(false);
```

And in layout:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Setting the background in the layout *completely removes the under bar*, as apposed to just hiding it in code.

Make it editable again with:

```
ET.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```