# How to make android:lineSpacingMultiplier behaves same for both EditText and TextView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I tend to create `TextView` and `EditText`, which looks visually pixel identical.

I overlay an `EditText` with `TextView`, so that I can compare their identical. I make `TextView` having red color text.

This is how they looks like so far.

### `EditText` and `TextView` looks identical without `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`

[image]

This is the XML being used

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body_text_view"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/body_edit_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

However, when comes with `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`, both behaves differently.

### `EditText` and `TextView` looks different with `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`

[image]

This is the XML being used

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body_text_view"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2.4" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/body_edit_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2.4" />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

May I know, how to make android:lineSpacingMultiplier behaves same for both `EditText` and `TextView`, so that `EditText` and `TextView` can look visually identical?

### p/s

Please don't suggest using `EditText` as replacement for `TextView`. They are not the same! You can have all sort of workaround trying to make `EditText` behave like `TextView`. (Stackoverflow has tone of suggestions on workaround. None of them will work **perfectly**) At the end of the day, it doesn't work!

Comment: Why don't you use both `EditText` and make the first `EditText` `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: Making `android:focusable="false"` won't make `EditText` behave 100% like `TextView`. I can't remember the exact details. But believe me, I tried countless time and it surely doesn't behave like `TextView`.

Comment: The `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView` - so except for editing, what applies to `TextView` applies to `EditText` as well. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4989545/7666442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditText` is an extension (subclass) of `TextView`, yet the two are behaving differently here and that certainly is **because of their unsimilar properties (either set from xml or those unsimilar by default)**. So the only way to align them perfectly is to look for those unsimilar properties that might be causing the issue and make them behave alike.
Considering **"May I know, how to make android:lineSpacingMultiplier behaves same for both EditText and TextView, so that EditText and TextView can look visually identical?"** as your main concern,
I was able to align them perfectly by altering the following attributes of `TextView`.

[As stated in this document (TextView class).](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

> **android:editable**
>
> If set, specifies that this TextView has an input method. It will be a textual one unless it has otherwise been specified. For TextView, this is **false by default**. For EditText, it is **true by default**.

This attribute has been deprecated but it can be replaced by

> **android:inputType**
>
> The type of data being placed in a text field, used to help an input method decide how to let the user enter text. The constants here correspond to those defined by InputType. Generally you can select a single value, though some can be combined together as indicated. **Setting this attribute to anything besides *none* also implies that the text is editable.**

To make it work efficiently use `textMultiLine` because your `EditText` has the same property.

> **android:breakStrategy**
>
> Sets the break strategy for breaking paragraphs into lines. The default value for TextView is Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_HIGH_QUALITY, and the default value for EditText is Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE, the latter to avoid the text "dancing" when being edited.

**In a nutshell**, adding

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:breakStrategy="simple"
```

to the `TextView` will place them exactly at the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, adding

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

or

```
android:editable="true"
```

to the **TextView** seems to solve the problem

This does not make the textview really editable, and in fact it doesn't make sense, but it changes the effect of the `lineSpacingMultiplier` attribute.

Comment: Your solution (setting `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`) works well in adjusting vertically, but surprisingly the text may [horizontally doesn't match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVTKf.png) :-|

Comment: the problem was surprising in the first place (considering an `EditText` is more or less a `TextView` with a different theming), but this is just weird

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `lineSpacingMultiplier`, use `lineSpacingExtra` and simply c**alculate with the multiplier** you want to apply in the code.

I **was able** to replicate your problem on my machine, and indeed `lineSpacingMultiplier`produces the same problem you were facing with, and couldn't find any solution/reason to why this would happen **(not even on the Android Docs)**.

However, when I changed it to the same `lineSpacingExtra`, for example: `lineSpacingExtra = 20dp`, **they were perfectly aligned.**

So basically , you can calculate the spacing you want for your `EditText` and `TextView`, and apply that value through code like this:

```
float calculatedValue = 50.0f;
editText.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, calculatedValue,  getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 1.0f);
textView.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, calculatedValue,  getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 1.0f);
```

This approach worked for me, even when I played around with the `calculatedValue`,the text of **both elements always aligns perfectly.**

This is the xml I ended up using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body_text_view"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/body_edit_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Image with line spacing set to 50 on both `EditText` And `TextView`:

[image: Image with line spacing set to 50 on both <code>EditText</code> And <code>TextView</code>:]

Answer (score 0):

```
    lineSpacingExtra with 2dp worked fine for me but I was wondering what the Multiplier does instead?`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:text="An editable text view that shows completion suggestions ... When you define an edit text widget, you must specify the R.styleable. .... android:lineSpacingMultiplier"
                android:id="@+id/body_text_view"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <EditText
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:text="An editable text view that shows completion suggestions ... When you define an edit text widget, you must specify the R.styleable. .... android:lineSpacingMultiplier"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`



2nd way Not  android:lineSpacingMultiplier=" " use LineSpacingExtra insteed   LineSpacingMultiplier

 android:lineSpacingExtra="1.5dp"



  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:lineSpacingExtra="1.5dp"
            android:text="An editable text view that shows completion suggestions ... When you define an edit text widget, you must specify the R.styleable. .... android:lineSpacingMultiplier DD"
            android:id="@+id/body_text_view"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <EditText
            android:lineSpacingExtra="1.5dp"
            android:text="An editable text view that shows completion suggestions ... When you define an edit text widget, you must specify the R.styleable. .... android:lineSpacingMultiplier D"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following 2 in `TextView` solves my problem

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```